# VCL application using TWebBrowser vs. Callback to Delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

For a certain situation I am using a TWebBrowser component in order to show user-customizeable visualization in my Delphi Application. The HTML page uses JavaScript to make special things to happen. But now I also need to call some Delphi functions from the JavaScript which also has to evaluate on the return values of this Dephi code.
What is the best way for doing it?

Comment: [How to call Delphi code from scripts running in a TWebBrowser](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=1)

Comment: very detailed! THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

You can run a local http server written in Delphi (using Indy, Synapse, ...) which can be called from JavaScript either with traditional HTTP requests and JSON or XML payload (Ajax), or asynchronously with WebSockets.

The Delphi HTTP server then handles the request, 'makes special things to happen', and returns the response.